# Changing "Unfortunately app has stopped message" to some other text

Tags: android

I have a app which requests for a lot of JSON arrays, if there is no internet signal , JSON is a null pointer reference due to which my app crashes. Instead of writing a  function to check if the JSONArray is null, can I change the text of `Unfortunately app stopped working` to `Cannot connect to internet`?

Is this possible?

Comment: for that you have to write you own SDK

Comment: You cannot. you have to handle null pointer

Comment: Catch this exception and show a dialog with the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the text of the `NullPointerException` unless you develop your own Exception class and a SDK.

But for now this is what you can do.

```
try
{
 // try to parse your json here
}
catch(NullPointerException npe)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Cannot connect to internet")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish(); // Close your app
               }
           });
   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   alert.show();
}
```